# Why am I getting this error when I try to switch HTML pages

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I made basic HTML/CSS files, that I'm trying to run through Django, but every time I run it and try to switch pages, I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about.html
Using the URLconf defined in test.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='main']
add [name='about']
The current path, about.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

Here's what that my .urls file looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('add',views.about,name='main.html'),
    path('add',views.about,name='about.html')
]
```

Here's my .views file looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def main(request):
    return render(request,'main.html')
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

Lastly Here's the section of my Settings file that I modified to find the file:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
```

Is there something else I'm supposed to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is here you should add the name of the URL of the page as an example http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

PS - in `urls.py` should write it like this home/

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Here/main.html/',views.main,name='main.html'),
    path('here/about.html/',views.about ,name='about.html')
]
```

**UPDATE 05/01/2022**

**Follow these steps to get the same result**

- Run-on your terminal `django-admin startproject Tuto` and `django-admin startapp tutoApp` like you're did in this project.
- Go to `settings.py` and add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`
- Create a folder on your TutoApp and name it `templates` and create the following file `index.html`, `about.html`.
- Go to `settings.py` `import os` and on **TEMPLATES** change `'DIRS': []` with `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR),'templates']`
- You need to add some functions to your `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

- In /tuto/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('tutoApp.urls'))

]
```

- Back to you're app and create a file name `urls.py`

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.homepage),
    path('about/', views.about)
]
```

add some HTML to these pages to recognize which page you're on.

- Run `python3 manage.py runserver` and go to
  [Home Page](http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/)
  [About page](http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/)

Comment: I have tried this, and it did not work going to play with some other stuff to see If I can figure it out.

Comment: I would update the answer and I will explain each step

Comment: @David_Codes Answer updated

Comment: Thank you, I followed the steps and got it to work. I think the biggest thing I forgot was to add the app name into the settings installed apps section.

Comment: I have a follow up question. If I have a html button that I want to link to another page, what extra steps would I need to take?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `about` view, you should add this path to `urlpatterns`:

```py
path('about/', views.about)
```

Then you can access it through `/about/` URL **not** `/about.html`, the same as for `main` view.

Comment: Just tried this method after the first comment and I got it to give me access to the homepage, but not the about.html page. I think it may be tied to me not using jinga in my html files.

Comment: What do you mean by 'homepage'? do you mean that when referring to `/about/` you get the same page as referring to the `/` URL?

Comment: I meant my main.html file, sorry about that.

Comment: Accessing `/about/` renders the `main.html` file means that you're rendering the `main.html` file in the `about` view, or the `/about/` URL isn't tied to the `about` view.